# Auto login to facebook using php sdk (PHP)

Tags: php, facebook

So i current have a script to login to facebook by clicking the login button my website,
This will be on app.facebook.com/********
So ideally want it to auto login like other games do.

Will have active SSL etc and will support mysqli etc

```
<?php
 // Include FB config file && User class
 require_once 'fbConfig.php';
 require_once 'User.php';

 if(isset($accessToken)){
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
}else{
    // Put short-lived access token in session
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

    // OAuth 2.0 client handler helps to manage access tokens
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

    // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
    $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

    // Set default access token to be used in script
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
}

// Redirect the user back to the same page if url has "code" parameter in query string
if(isset($_GET['code'])){
    header('Location: ./');
}

// Getting user facebook profile info
try {
    $profileRequest = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture');
    $fbUserProfile = $profileRequest->getGraphNode()->asArray();
} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    session_destroy();
    // Redirect user back to app login page
    header("Location: ./");
    exit;
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

// Initialize User class
$user = new User();

// Insert or update user data to the database
$fbUserData = array(
    'oauth_provider'=> 'facebook',
    'oauth_uid'     => $fbUserProfile['id'],
    'first_name'    => $fbUserProfile['first_name'],
    'last_name'     => $fbUserProfile['last_name'],
    'email'         => $fbUserProfile['email'],
    'gender'        => $fbUserProfile['gender'],
    'locale'        => $fbUserProfile['locale'],
    'picture'       => $fbUserProfile['picture']['url'],
    'link'          => $fbUserProfile['link']
);
$userData = $user->checkUser($fbUserData);

// Put user data into session
$_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;

// Get logout url
$logoutURL = $helper->getLogoutUrl($accessToken, $redirectURL.'logout.php');

// Render facebook profile data
if(!empty($userData)){
    $output  = '<h1>Facebook Profile Details </h1>';
    $output .= '<img src="'.$userData['picture'].'">';
    $output .= '<br/>Facebook ID : ' . $userData['oauth_uid'];
    $output .= '<br/>Name : ' . $userData['first_name'].' '.$userData['last_name'];
    $output .= '<br/>Email : ' . $userData['email'];
    $output .= '<br/>Gender : ' . $userData['gender'];
    $output .= '<br/>Locale : ' . $userData['locale'];
    $output .= '<br/>Logged in with : Facebook';
    $output .= '<br/><a href="'.$userData['link'].'" target="_blank">Click to Visit Facebook Page</a>';
    $output .= '<br/>Logout from <a href="'.$logoutURL.'">Facebook</a>'; 
}else{
    $output = '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>';
}

}else{
// Get login url
    $loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $fbPermissions);

// Render facebook login button
$output = '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($loginURL).'"><img src="images/fblogin-btn.png"></a>';
```

}
    ?>

HTML:

```
<body>
<!-- Display login button / Facebook profile information -->
<div><?php echo $output; ?></div>
</body>
```

Comment: ok, but...what is the issue? any errors? where are you stuck?

Comment: You need manually click the login button (even on the apps.facebook.com)

I want change it so when you load the apps.facebook.com/mygamename it automatically logs you in?

Comment: ok, we know that, but you just presented the code and told us what you want. what EXACTLY does not work? does the token not get stored in the session?

Comment: That leads to a very bad user experience. People usually want to know what an app has to offer first, before they decide to log in to it for the first time - just throwing the login dialog into everyone’s faces first thing is likely going to cost you users. Users that already logged in to your app before and return to it can be recognized automatically; so you should really consider keeping it so that new users need to explicitly click a button to login.